# Why and Where do we use down casting?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, oop

Are there any cases where we do down casting of objects?

If we do, why?

I have observed a way of hiding implementation using the below code. Is this the correct way to do? Is there any better way to achieve the same.

```
class A{
    public:
      A();
      virtual ~A();
      //exposed virtual functions
};

class AImpl : public A{
    public:
       AImpl(A *obj);
       virtual ~AImpl();     
      //exposed virtual functions++
};

class Helper{ //utility class so i am making constructor and assignment operator as private
    public:
       static bool doWork(A *obj){
          AImpl *objImpl = dynamic_cast<AImpl *> (obj);
          return doWork(objImpl); // some internal function
       }

    private:
         Helper();
         Helper(const Helper& obj);
         const Helper& operator=(const Helper& obj);
};
```

The question still does not makes sense. I agree. I still have not figured out a proper way of hiding the implementation details from the client.

**UncleBens**
I termed this thing wrongly as Object slicing. Basically, I was referring to this (Object Slicing) as the information related to derived part is missing.

**S.Soni**
Thanks for giving a wonderful explaination. Now, I can really put forward question.

Consider a clients perspective. The only class which are visible to him is class A and the Helper class (because I have hidden implementation behind AImpl

Client has to write the following code as he is unaware of AImpl class

```
int main(){
    A *a = new A();
    Helper.doWork(a);
    // ...
}
```

As you said AImpl * in this case will actually be pointing to the base class object, which is wrong (you have explained it with a great example), so this approach of hiding implementation is not correct.

Any attempt to access a derived class member function will result in a crash (and correctly so).

How should I go about hiding the implementation in this case? This is a design problem now?

Comment: This question still doesn't make sense. dynamic_cast only works on polymorphic types (you must have some virtual methods). But if A were polymorphic, why would you need to downcast it?

Comment: I don't understand why down_casting would lead to object_slicing...

Comment: removed object slicing as downcasting does not slice an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**Are there any cases where we do down casting of objects**
```

The purpose of dynamic_cast is to perform casts on polymorphic types. For
example, given two polymorphic classes Band D, with D derived from B, a
dynamic_cast can always cast a D* pointer into a B* pointer. This is because a base
pointer can always point to a derived object. But a dynamic_cast can cast a B* pointer
into a D* pointer only if the object being pointed to actually is a D object.

```
**`Is there any better way to achieve the same`**
```

Perhaps the most important of the new casting operators is dynamic_cast. The
dynamic_cast performs a run-time cast that verifies the validity of a cast.

1) Your class is not polymorphic.A class that declares or inherits a virtual function      is called a polymorphic class

2) Syntax of dynamic_cast is **dynamic__cast (expr)**

**1st Edit :**

Try like this , it will work

```
class A
{
    public:
      A();
      virtual ~A();// Notice here i have put virtual
};

class AImpl : public A
{
    public:
       AImpl(A *obj);
       ~AImpl();     
};

class Helper
{
    public:
        Helper(){}
       static bool doWork(A *obj)
       {
          AImpl *objImpl = dynamic_cast<AImpl*> (obj);
          return true;
       }
};
```

Study this example :

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "Inside Base\n"; }
    // ...
};
class Derived: public Base 
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "Inside Derived\n"; }
};


int main()
{  
    Base *bp, b_ob;
    Derived *dp, d_ob;
    dp = dynamic_cast<Derived *> (&d_ob);
    if(dp) {
        cout << "Cast from Derived * to Derived * OK.\n";
        dp->f();
    } else

        cout << "Error\n";
    cout << endl;
    bp = dynamic_cast<Base *> (&d_ob);
    if(bp) {
        cout << "Cast from Derived * to Base * OK.\n";
        bp->f();
    } else
        cout << "Error\n";
    cout << endl;
    bp = dynamic_cast<Base *> (&b_ob);
    if(bp) {
        cout << "Cast from Base * to Base * OK.\n";
        bp->f();
    } else
        cout << "Error\n";
    cout << endl;
    dp = dynamic_cast<Derived *> (&b_ob);
    if(dp)
        cout << "Error\n";
    else
        cout << "Cast from Base * to Derived * not OK.\n";
    cout << endl;
    bp = &d_ob; // bp points to Derived object
    dp = dynamic_cast<Derived *> (bp);
    if(dp) {
        cout << "Casting bp to a Derived * OK\n" <<
            "because bp is really pointing\n" <<
            "to a Derived object.\n";
        dp->f();
    } else
        cout << "Error\n";
    cout << endl;
    bp = &b_ob; // bp points to Base object
    dp = dynamic_cast<Derived *> (bp);
    if(dp)
        cout << "Error";
    else {
        cout << "Now casting bp to a Derived *\n" <<
            "is not OK because bp is really \n" <<
            "pointing to a Base object.\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    dp = &d_ob; // dp points to Derived object
    bp = dynamic_cast<Base *> (dp);
    if(bp) {
        cout << "Casting dp to a Base * is OK.\n";
        bp->f();
    } else
        cout << "Error\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "dynamic_cast can cast a B* pointer into a D* pointer only if the object being pointed to actually is a D object"

Can you explain this using an example. In the example I quoted above I am trying to cast a A* pointer to AImpl* pointer which is actually  a A object. so, according to you this is wrong.

What approach should i be using in the case above. (Hope I have been able to make you understand my problem)

Answer (score 1):

Your example code contains at least 4 syntax errors, so it's hard to judge what you're trying to do.

And it logically won't work either. You have a class `AImpl` that inherits `A`, then a member function that takes an `A` and appears to try to dynamic-cast it to an `AImpl`. But it isn't an `AImpl`, because it's just an `A`, as that is how the parameter is declared. If you were to  pass an instance of `AImpl` to that function, it would be sliced down to just an `A`.

You could make it a reference or pointer to an `A`, and then it could be an `AImpl`. Dynamic casts are only ever of use on references or pointers.

Down-casting is used when we have a variable or parameter that has the static type of a base class but we logically know that it is (or might be) of a derived class. It is avoided wherever possible because it means that the compilation process is not able to completely check the type-correctness of the program, i.e. the answer to the question "are you trying to put a square peg into a round hole" cannot be fully answered until runtime.

**Update after question was edited**

It sounds like you want clients of your library to have access to a limited interface to an object, A, but when they pass it to a function in your library you will have access to the full interface. You could just use `friend` for this.

```
class A
{
    friend class LibraryThing;

    void visibleToLibraryThing();

public:
    // ctor, etc.

    void visibleToAll();
};

class LibraryThing
{
public:
    void foo(A &a)
    {
        a.visibleToLibraryThing();
    }
};
```

The `LibraryThing` class can access the private members of `A`, because it is declared as a friend of `A`.

The downside is that `LibraryThing` can access *everything* in `A`, so it means that as the author of the library, you won't be able to benefit from encapsulation. Only users of your library will.

Comment: You are so quick. I have made the corrections.
Basically I am trying to hide class AImpl using dynamic_cast

See, if the code now makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

From your code and the information that the passed in pointer actually points to an A, and not an AImpl, also the constructor AImpl that accepts an A*, I gather that what you want it:

```
class Helper{
    public:
       static bool doWork(A *obj){
          AImpl objImpl(obj); //construct an AImpl instance, using available constructor
          return doWork(&objImpl); // some internal function
       }
};
```

There is no way to **cast** a base instance into an instance of a derived class (where would the missing derived part come from??).

Comment: yes! i am trying to clarify my doubts here. sometimes i feel myself in the middle of so much confusion... that I find hard to explain my question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the following holds true (not the only valid reasons, but a common one):

- you have a MVC like architecture
- you want to hide the implementation details from client code (no-na...)
- you need to pass some references from core to client-code (handles of all sorts, etc.)
- the only valid implementation of the public interfaces must be in the core of the MVC part

then using this way is quite common.

However, if it is simply not *allowed* to use any other implementation (because only your library core may implement the interface), then asserting the type would be nice too; this would provide a nice landing in the debugger or crash-dump for any user of the library who messed with it in a way it should not be done.  Of course, the documentation should clearly indicate that deriving from `A` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIMPL to hide implementation details, mask dependencies, and speed up builds.

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm

[http://www.ddj.com/cpp/205918714](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm)

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm